# Installing C SDK for couchbase, Mac OSX 10.6.8 -- How can I correct cmake errors?

Tags: cmake, couchbase, libcouchbase

I am trying to get couchbase up and running for python on Mac OSX 10.6.8.  I'm following the instructions here:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-python-1.2/index.html#getting-started

But I'm stuck on step 2:

> Download and install the C library.

According to the instructions for installing the C SDK here:

http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/download-install.html

I did this:

```
~$ brew update
....
....
~$ brew install libcouchbase
```

But I'm getting an error when homebrew tries to install the dependency `cmake`:

```
==> Installing libcouchbase dependency: cmake
==> Downloading http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.1/cmake-3.1.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake-3.1.0.tar.gz
==> Patching
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Sphinx/Sphinx-1.2.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--sphinx-1.2.3.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-HcEaFf/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-e
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MarkupSafe/MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--markupsafe-0.23.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-HcEaFf/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-e
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/docutils/docutils-0.12.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--docutils-0.12.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-HcEaFf/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-e
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pygments/Pygments-2.0.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--pygments-2.0.1.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-HcEaFf/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-e
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/J/Jinja2/Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-HcEaFf/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-e
==> ./bootstrap --prefix=/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.1.0 --system-libs --parallel=2 --no-system-libarchiv
==> make
[ 34%] Building C object Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/archive_write_set_options.c.o
[ 34%] Building C object Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/cmlibarchive.dir/filter_fork_posix.c.o
Linking C static library libcmlibarchive.a
[ 34%] Built target cmlibarchive
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
Fix LLVM CMake modules not being preprocessed (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/29976)
cmake builds fail on CLT-only with --env=std (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29101)
```

More detail here:

```
~$ brew gist-logs --config --doctor cmake
https://gist.github.com/a37987f168d284128cfe
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I should do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got XCode version 3.2.6 installed, which I believe is the highest version compatible with OSX 10.6.8.

In the gist, whose link I posted, one of the errors is:

```
 error: ncurses/ncurses.h: No such file or directory
```

I found ncurses.h on my system here:

```
/usr/include$ ls -al ncurses.h
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 Aug 11  2012 ncurses.h -> curses.h
```

...which if you note is not in a directory called ncurses(look at the prompt)--ncurses being the directory where the error message says ncurses.h should be.  Also, note that ncurses.h is a link to another file: curses.h (see the arrow on the right?).  So, I did this:

```
/usr/include$ sudo mkdir ncurses
Password:

/usr/include$ cd ncurses

/usr/include/ncurses$ sudo cp -av ../ncurses.h .   (-a => copy link rather than the file it points to, -v => verbose, show what is being copied)
Password:
../ncurses.h -> ./ncurses.h

/usr/include/ncurses$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   102 Dec 29 18:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  272 root  wheel  9248 Dec 29 18:13 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     8 Dec 29 18:59 ncurses.h -> curses.h
```

Then I tried installing libcouchbase again:

```
~$ brew install libcouchbase 
==> Installing libcouchbase dependency: cmake
==> Downloading http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.1/cmake-3.1.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake-3.1.0.tar.gz
==> Patching
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/J/Jinja2/Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-FqXEf3/cmake-3.1
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MarkupSafe/MarkupSafe-0.23.ta
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--markupsafe-0.23.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-FqXEf3/cmake-3.1
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/docutils/docutils-0.12.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--docutils-0.12.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-FqXEf3/cmake-3.1
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pygments/Pygments-2.0.1.tar.g
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--pygments-2.0.1.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-FqXEf3/cmake-3.1
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Sphinx/Sphinx-1.2.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake--sphinx-1.2.3.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-FqXEf3/cmake-3.1
==> ./bootstrap --prefix=/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.1.0 --system-libs --para
==> make
==> make install
/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.1.0: 1819 files, 33M, built in 18.5 minutes
==> Installing libcouchbase
==> Downloading http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/c/libcouchbase-2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf.t
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_
==> make install
/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf: 53 files, 1.4M, built in 42 seconds
$
```

I didn't believe it, so I tried again:

```
~$ brew install libcouchbase 
Warning: libcouchbase-2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf already installed

~$ brew uninstall libcouchbase
Uninstalling /Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf...

~$ brew install libcouchbase
==> Downloading http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/c/libcouchbase-2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf.t
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libcouchbase-2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf.tar.gz
==> Patching
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_
==> make install
/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf: 53 files, 1.4M, built in 30 seconds
~$
```

Testing the install:

```
/usr/include/ncurses$ cbc version
cbc:
  Runtime: Version=2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf, Changeset=d7f6ecfa15e73c668a8f81947d9f85b654dcdbda
  Headers: Version=2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf, Changeset=d7f6ecfa15e73c668a8f81947d9f85b654dcdbda
  IO: Default=libevent, Current=libevent
  SSL: .. SUPPORTED
```

## Python SDK

But then I was unable to install the Python SDK following the instructions here:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-python-1.2/

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
```

I got to here:

```
5. Install the Python SDK. The easiest way to do this is via the pip tool:

shell> pip install couchbase --quiet
```

But this is what happened:

> $  pip install couchbase --quiet
>   Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-eflT9C-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 9,
>   in 
>       load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/**init**.py",
>   line 148, in main
>       return command.main(args[1:], options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 169, in main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)

Same thing here:

> $   LC_ALL=C pip install couchbase --quiet
>
> Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-Oe6ydu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase
>   Storing complete log in /Users/7stud/.pip/pip.log
>   /usr/include/ncurses$  pip install couchbase --quiet Command
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-GijsbQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 9,
>   in 
>       load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/**init**.py",
>   line 148, in main
>       return command.main(args[1:], options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 169, in main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)

I fixed the unicode error by patching the python source code:

```
 #text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
 #python 2.x patch found here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137
 text = '\n'.join(to_utf8(l) for l in complete_log)
```

But then I got this error:

> $  pip install couchbase --quiet
>   Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-AQtdf2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_7stud/couchbase
>   Storing complete log in /Users/7stud/.pip/pip.log
>   $

(I just looked at the error log mentioned above: pip.log, and it says the error was a KeyboardInterrupt.  Huh?  So, I tried `$ pip install couchbase --quiet` again and it worked.  Then, to test the install `$ python -c 'import couchbase'`, and there were no errors!  I don't know if the stuff I did below influenced anything.)

Next, I decided to try installing from source:

According to the README file:

```
~/Downloads/couchbase-1.2.4$  python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But that ended like this:

> src/exceptions.c:136: error: too many arguments to function
>   ‘pycbc_exc_map’ lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:
>   /var/folders/++/++iEr0qoGaimgUBsnNcijk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccZekvJj.out error:
>   command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Next, I did this:

> ~/Downloads/couchbase-1.2.4$  python setup.py build_ext \
>   > --library-dir ~/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf/lib \
>   > --include-dir ~/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf/include
>
> running build_ext building 'couchbase._libcouchbase' extension gcc-4.2
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot
>   ...
>   ...
>    intel-2.7/src/iops.o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/connevents.o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/pipeline.o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/viewrow/viewrow.o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/contrib/jsonsl/jsonsl.o
>   -L/Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.5_1_gd7f6ecf/lib -lcouchbase -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/couchbase/_libcouchbase.so

...which ended without error.  But testing the install failed:

```
~/Downloads/couchbase-1.2.4$ python -c 'import couchbase'  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "couchbase/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from couchbase.connection import Connection
  File "couchbase/connection.py", line 22, in <module>
    import couchbase._bootstrap
  File "couchbase/_bootstrap.py", line 34, in <module>
    import couchbase.exceptions as E
  File "couchbase/exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    import couchbase._libcouchbase as C
ImportError: No module named _libcouchbase
```

So, I thought what the heck, I'll go ahead and try this:

```
~/Downloads/couchbase-1.2.4$ python setup.py install
...
...
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for couchbase==1.2.4
Finished processing dependencies for couchbase==1.2.4
```

But, I got the same import error when testing the install, so I gave up.

After reading the answer to my question, I did:

```
$ brew install gcc
```

but I didn't try to fix couchbase until now.  I don't think installing gcc with homebrew did anything because I still get:

> ~$ gcc --version
>   i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc.
>   build 5666) (dot 3) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There
>   is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> /usr/bin$ which gcc
>   /usr/bin/gcc
>
> /usr/bin$ ls -al /usr/bin/gcc
>   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Aug 11  2012 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.2

...which is the Apple version of gcc.  But, when I installed gcc with homebrew I got the output:

> /Users/7stud/.homebrew/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1: 1155 files, 200M, built in
>   106.8 minutes

...which is gcc version 4.9.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest (available for 10.6.8) version of Xcode and its devtools? It appears to be an issue with GCC (I initially had issues with the LLVM gcc version Apple packages with Xcode).

Try `brew install gcc` (or `brew reinstall gcc` if you initially used brew to install gcc) and then run `brew install make` again.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I posted additional info in my answer.